# Atom Editor - Can´t write the ':' character

Tags: atom-editor

I installed some plugins ([autoclose-html](https://atom.io/packages/autoclose-html)), and now I cannot write the `:` character. If I disable it, I can write this back, but if I enable it another time, I get the problem.

How can I fix this? How can I change the plugin not to override my keys?

I've also [filed a bug report](https://github.com/mattberkowitz/autoclose-html/issues/138).

Comment: Could you please add your autoclose-html version, keyboard layout, os and language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate Legacy/International Mode works for me

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using an international keyboard layout. I run into this issue as well with 2 different international layouts (PT and SE).

As of v.0.23.0 Legacy/International Mode has been added. if you activate it in settings, it should solve your issue.

Comment: @programador-adagal why did you accept the most recent answer instead of mine?